Laggy scroll on Firefox when using anchor
I made a website with collapsible section using anchor tags: each section has the following structure.
<div class="target" id="project-id"> </div>
<div class="proj">
<a class="projline" href="#project-id"></a>
   <div class="content wrap">
     content of project
   </div>
</div>

Each section scrolls to top when clicked, and .content changes from display: none; to display: block; (essentially)
The problem is the following: it works very smoothly on safari, chrome, opera, but looks very laggy on firefox. I'm wondering if you know why? It's hard to spot since it works on the other browsers btw. My version is 133.0
Here is a website demo: https://mar_ver.gitlab.io/specss/
.content {
    width: var(--projline);
    padding: 0 var(--num) 0 var(--idw);
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    transition: padding .3s;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: var(--pad4) var(--pad4);
    margin: 0 var(--pad);
}

.target:target+ .line +.proj .projline {
    cursor: default;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: var(--pad4);
    transition: margin .3s
}

.target:target+ .line + .proj {
    cursor: default;
    border-color: #000;
    border-top-width: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: var(--padish);
}
.target:target+ .line + header.proj {
    position: relative;
    /* no sticky here or no scroll */
}

.target:target + .line +.proj .hide, .target:target + .line .hide {
    display: block
}
.target:target+ .line +.proj .show {
    visibility: hidden
}

.target:target + .line +.proj .content {
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: var(--pad6);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: padding-bottom .3s
}


I looked at your demo site using Firefox 133.0.3 on Windows 11 24H2 and I don't notice anything particular laggy when scrolling. Perhaps you need to refresh Firefox? Too many buggy plugins?

Did you try clicking on the different sections, like on windmill? For me it sort of jitters when I do that.

On FF133, I see no problems. I'd toast the opening animations, but that's a different issue.
